# How to best code a problem with scipy, cvxpy or Convex.jl with given generated data

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

I have a curve fitting problem of the form:
$$
\textbf{y} = f(\textbf{x}, a,b,c,d) + \varepsilon
$$
$$
f(x, a,b,c,d) = \frac{b}{e^{x\cdot a}+c}+d
$$
with the constraint
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \arg\min_{a,b,c,d} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(f(\text{x})_i-\text{y}_i)^2}\\
  \textrm{s.t.} \quad & -c-\frac{b}{d}-1 = 0\\
  \quad & a = 1   \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where

- $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}$ are the data given by an experiment
- $a \in \mathbb{R}$
- $b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $c \in \mathbb{R}$
- $d \in \mathbb{R}$
  Note: $a = 1$ because this parameter is being measured by a measurement in an experience and is, therefore fixed.

The simulated data and the following code are as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 20
np.random.seed(1)
def sigm01(x,a,b,c,d):
  return b/(np.exp(x*a)+c)+d

start = -10
end = -start
x = np.arange(start,end,0.01)
a = 1
b = -2
c = 1
d = 1
y = sigm01(x,a,b,c,d) + np.random.randn(len(x))/10
#plt.plot(x,y)
#plt.show()
```

I would like to use an optimization package (such as `scipy`, `cvxpy` or `Convex.jl`).

How could I setup the problem?

Comment: So a,b,c are fixed and you're minimizing with respect to x?

Comment: thanks for your comment @Richard. No $x$ is given. ($\textbf{x}$  and $\textbf{y}$ are the data). And I want to find the optimal $a,b,c,d$ to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(\text{x}_i-\text{y}_i)^2}$. It is a curve fitting problem

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify? `d` should be part of the argmin and the phrase "a=1 in the generated data" seems confusing.

Comment: @Richard. I edited the question

Comment: Is there any reason why you have that weird cost function $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||^2$ instead of least square? I mean are you sure you are not looking for $||\mathbf{y}-f(\mathbf{x})||^2$? Cause I have a hard time understanding why you want to minimize the distance between measured $\mathbf{y}$ and your features $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AloneProgrammer. Indeed you're right, it was a mistake. I changed the question accordingly

Comment: In its current form you can solve this problem easily with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, with the 2 constraints? How would you code it?

Comment: Those constraints are not basically constraints in a classical definition. One of them is simply a given parameter for $a$ which you can replace $a$ with 1 everywhere. The other one just replaces $c$ with $b$ and $d$ everywhere and then finally you just fit $\mathbf{y}$ to $f(\mathbf{x},b,d)$. Simply the scipy’s example given in their documentation works perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your constraints of $a = 1$ and $c = -\frac{b}{d} - 1$, your $f$ looks like this:

$$\hat{\mathbf{y}} = f(\mathbf{x},b,d) = \frac{bd}{d\exp{(\mathbf{x})}-b - d} + d$$

You're trying to solve a **nonlinear least square** problem basically:

$$b,d = \arg \min \sum_{i=1}^{N} (f(x_{i})-y_{i})^{2}$$

It's a job for `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x,b,d):
    return ((b*d)/(d*np.exp(x)-b-d))+d

xdata = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)
y = func(xdata, -2, 1)
np.random.seed(1729)
y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([-3, 0], [-1, 2.]))

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: b=%5.3f, d=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('curve_fit.png')
plt.show()
```

The final fit looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Happy Holidays! I hope things are well with you.

Comment: @Richard Happy holidays and thanks for your kind message!